# jQuery UnSlider — Prevent Slider from "Rewinding"

Tags: javascript, jquery

See source here http://pastebin.com/9W7a3z2w to make sure we are referencing the same version.

Basically now after a slider finishes, it rewinds back to slide one. I need it to actually just go in reverse. So 3->2->1->2->3

This is out of my limited JS knowledge and the unslider creator calls such a feature a helluva hack which worries me https://github.com/idiot/unslider/issues/54

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: well to be honest, im not even sure where to start. i assume in the  _.play function, we would need to figure out if we are at the end of the list of slides.

Comment: Why not just use a better plugin that provides reverse option?

Comment: The author of the plugin seems extremely helpful... You may want to look for an alternative plugin or give it a try yourself, though from a design/UX perspective, why would you want it to reverse?

Answer (score 0):

Try flexslider2. It's responsive and has a reverse option:

***reverse: false, //{NEW} Boolean: Reverse the animation direction***